# MagSafe LED sometimes won't light up

Tags: macbook-pro, display, power, magsafe, logicboard

I have a Mid 2014 MacBook Pro with Retina Display. As of a week ago, occasionally when I plugged in the MagSafe Adapter, the LED doesn't light up. The problem is fixed by unplugging the power adapter from the MacBook and plugging it back in.

Should I worry with this? Is it an indicator for something wrong?

Last time I remember with my previous MBP, I had the same issue and it was getting worse, and then the logic board died.

Comment: Is it only the light (i.e. it does charge when it doesn't lit up?). Try resetting the SMC (System Management Controller): https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Comment: No, it doesn't charge but indeed the lcd become brighter when the magsfae plugged in, but it's not charging.Yes, I have reset the SMC and it's indeed fixed it, but the problem is coming back again later

Comment: OK so it's not just the light, but it's not charging. Are you able to try with another charger from a friend? Could just be the charger. If possible I suggest you visit a genius bar

Comment: Another charger is fine. I'm just abit worried because last time I had this problem with my previous mac, it ended with a failing / died logicboard. Anyway I usually leave the magsafe plugged in to power for a week, could this be the cause of this problem?
And unfortunately genius bar is not possible. There is no official apple store in my country

Comment: FWIW, I've had this minor issue for years with my Retina MacBook Pro 13" 2012, but it's never gotten worse so I've lived with it.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark but here goes.  I have a MBA and my magsafe LED sometimes wouldn't light up.  In my case, if I remove and rotate the magsafe, the LED comes on and charges the MBA.  It only works when the "good" side is on top.

Answer (score 3):

This issue can often be caused by debris in the MagSafe port, I sometimes get small metallic particles, attracted there by the magnet. If this is the case, brushing the port with a dry cotton swab can fix the problem ( see here: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT203207)